# Почему в играх непостоянная кадровая частота (FPS)?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Интересна технология по кадровой отрисовки игр.

В играх постоянная кадровая частота или она динамическая? Если постоянная то какая; если динамическая, то от чего зависит?

Прочитал в [википидия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) что к примеру для немого кино использовали постоянную кадровую частоту в 16 FPS. А в играх она динамическая что ли?

Что на самом деле измеряют измерители FPS? Больше похоже, что количество FPS, которые видео-карта может дать ещё, а не частоту кадров в игре.

Comment: В разных играх она **разная**.

Comment: Не пойму к какому вопросу этот ответ относится. У меня тут их 6. Имеете ввиду может быть постоянной, а может быть динамической? Тогда можете привести примеры?

Comment: А потому что не надо задавать больше одного вопроса в одном вопросе :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Почему в играх непостоянная кадровая частота (FPS)?

Потому что в каждый момент времени нагрузка по отрисовке кадров непостоянна - число объектов на экране меняется, дальность и объем видимости меняется, скорость с которой CPU готовит и "заказывает" новые кадры тоже разнится от многих факторов. Это в целом малопредсказуемый процесс (тем более что игрок может смотреть то в стену, то с высоты на почти всю местность).

> В играх постоянная кадровая частота или она динамическая? Если постоянная то какая; если динамическая, то от чего зависит?

По разному. Обычно динамическая, но ограниченная сверху частотой обновления экрана (60-75Гц, нередко больше). Ограничение называется V-Sync (вертикальная синхронизация). Частота обновления зависит от скорости с которой видеокарта успевает рендерить графику, от частоты дисплей. Больше чем частота дисплея показать принципиально невозможно, но, на 1 кадре на дисплее могут быть совмещены несколько кадров (сверху-вниз, по мере того как они приходят от видеокарты). Сейчас уже есть дисплеи с адаптивной частотой, подстраивающиеся под видеокарту.

> Прочитал в википидия что к примеру для немого кино использовали постоянную кадровую частоту в 16 FPS. А в играх она динамическая что ли?

Обычно динамическая - чем больше кадров в секунду, тем все плавнее выглядит.

> Что на самом деле измеряют измерители FPS? Больше похоже, что количество FPS, которые видео-карта может дать ещё, а не частоту кадров в игре.

FPS - это обычно количество кадров в секунду, которое отдает видеокарта (разные игры могут считать это число немного по разному). Считается как время поделенное на немного усредненный интервал между готовыми кадрами (например 1000мс / 16мс = 62fps). Что вы имеете ввиду под частотой кадров в игре неясно.

---

> Хочу понять как строятся сцены в играх, чтобы сделать подобную по кадровую отрисовку для canvas

Сцена в игре строится в общем-то (да простят мне такое упрощение) из треугольников, которые GPU умеет рисовать в нереально бешенных количествах, раскрашиваемых по правилам (текстурирование, пиксельные эффекты и т.п.) с вдвойне нереально бешенной скоростью. Все это рендерится в буфер (картинку) треугольник-за-треугольником, пиксель-за-пикселем. Как только картинка готова, она отдается на дисплей и начинает рисоваться следующая картинка.

Для canvas (без использования видеокарты?) обычно тоже делается буфер, куда рисуется кадр (средствами CPU), и как только кадр окончен, он отдается на холст canvas для вывода на экран, а тем временем уже рисуется следующий кадр. Это можно делать как последовательно, так и по таймеру, если вы хотите получить статичный FPS.

*P.S. На Javascript все несколько сложнее, т.к. добавляется еще слой с браузером и ОС и их компоновкой картинки для вывода на экран, тут я не очень в теме.*

Comment: Хочу понять как строятся сцены в играх, чтобы сделать подобную по кадровую отрисовку для canvas.

Comment: Можем обсудить в здешнем чате, если правила сайта и репутация позволят (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64099/rendering) или Skype - kromster80

Comment: О ОС и браузере здесь не стоит переживать. Я планирую на canvas сделать игру. Но так как это обычный холст для рисования, придется его обрабатывать иначе, при каждом движении перерисовывать всю сцену, как в играх. Если не перерисовывать, то один объект будучи нарисованный поверх сцены, при движении стирает её. И тут мне пришло в голову сравнение с другими играми, монитор ведь тоже не различает объекты, у него есть только пиксели. Вот что хотел сделать https://codepen.io/antonowano/pen/MvQZYZ

Comment: Темно зеленый - задняя сцена, светло зеленый - передняя, красный - герой. Ничего не стирается потому что сцена каждый раз перерисовывается.

Comment: Да. Практически всегда все перерисовывается. Иногда только какие-то вещи могут кэшироваться (типа миникарты). Т.к. сложные игры динамичны и там каждый кадр уникален. А в простых играх такая экономия просто не окупается, а лишь усложняет разработку.

Answer (score -1):

В кино каждый кадрик записан заранее и должен быть показан через некоторое время после предыдущего, именно для этого времени кадрик записан таким, каким он записан. Если вывести в другое время, то нарушится время. Показали Вы кадрик на 200 миллисекунд позже – мир фильма стал таким на те же 200 миллисекунд позже. И именно этим определяется, с какой скоростью в мире фильма ездят машины, падет снег, колышется листва, расходятся ГПВ от брошенного в реку камня... Все скорости и темпы в мире фильма определяются тем, для какого именно времени записаны изображающие всё это кадрики. Вообще весь ход времени фильма опирается на временную привязку кадриков. В игре кадрики не записаны, а вычисляются для каждого игрока во время самого игрового процесса. При этом вывести кадрик раньше физически невозможно, так как процессор занят другими расчётами от вычисления предыдущего кадрика до решения того, а куда вообще должен идти непись. Игрок бросил камень, положение этого камня в пространстве тоже надо вычислить. А ещё надо рассчитать, попал ли игрок в цель, стреляя из винтовки или из подствольного гранотомёта... А если не попал в цель, то куда-то он всё равно попал, надо отрисовать взрыв гранаты где-то мимо. А где именно? Это тоже надо рассчитать. А если вывести позже, то картинка будет недостаточно плавной и не отразит быстрых процессов. Теперь есть у нас время кадрика, надо рассчитать кадрик для этого времени.